# Controlo de movimento em VB

Tags: basic

Este é o código do movimento:

```
Private Sub Form5_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        Label46.Top = Label46.Top - 6

    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        Label46.Left = Label46.Left - 6

    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        Label46.Top = Label46.Top + 6

    End If

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        Label46.Left = Label46.Left + 6

    End If
```

O resto do form são os obstáculos, isto sempre funcionou para mover a label mas agora que acabei o resto do projeto, quando entro no form do jogo a label já nao se mexe...(e nem alterei nada no form além de por um:

```
Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow

End Sub
```

que já experimentei tirar e nada)

Alguém sabe qual poderá ser o erro?